# Can anyone explain to me the different between data class and entity in android?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, entity, data-class

I'm working on an android application and is a bit confuse over the 2 concepts. I don't know if I can (or should) use data class instead of entity, or inside entity... How should I differentiate these 2 ?

Comment: A `data class` is [a feature of Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html). An entity is [an aspect of creating a Room-based database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data). They are not really related. A Room entity can be a `data class`, but it could be just an ordinary `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you start using classes and when you have finished your project and want to link it to a database, enter the entities.

However, these are some differences:

- The entity classes need a constructor without parameters.
- The classes don’t have it, and use the jpa-plugin.
- Entity is used for create tables on the data bases and take it @Entity

Comment: Can I use a data class object in an entity? And can I use an entity inside an entity?